# Django redirect "/" to index of installed app

Tags: python, django, url, redirect, indexing

I'trying to redirect the / of my domain to point to a index in my "frontend" app.
I tried a lot of ways and all of them work. 
The problem is that my index_view is being called twice for every redirect.
Here is my top urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r'^$', lambda x: HttpResponseRedirect('/frontend/')),
     url(r'^frontend/', include('frontend.urls', namespace="frontend")),
)
```

And here is my frontend/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^alert/create/$', views.create_alert, name="create_alert"),
    url(r'^alert/edit/(\w+)', views.edit_alert, name="edit_alert"),
)
```

Every time I go to / is calling my views.index twice and I can't see why =/
Am I doing the redirecting wrong ?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Basically what's happening is that you're saying for every request that is not a `frontend/` mapping issue a redirect. This would then trigger when a post has been made to your `create_alert` then when redirecting to your lambda (which im not sure why you have there, you're effectively turning your urls.py into a view. bad idea.) you issue a redirect thusly hitting the index twice since the index's regexp is the same as your redirect.

Comment: Thanks. Changed to do the redirect in the view and worked.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the root to use your FE url patterns like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include('frontend.urls', namespace="frontend")),
)
```

If you wanna forcibly redirect to /frontend/ then you will need a view to handle the redirect.

Maybe look at the Redirect Generic view: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-redirect-to

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But I've already tried that and my views.index method is still being called twice =/